# how to do auto Tslint in Intellij

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-14, tslint

I am using Intellij for doing angular project.  I am getting a lot of tslint errors while writing the code.Is there any way to fix all the these lint errors in by using a command in intellij ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the quick way to fix all the tslint errors would be to install visual studio code.

It will have the auto-fix option to fix option to fix all the issues

Event [`intellij`](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/webstorm-2017-1-eap-171-2455/) has the option to do the same

**`Alt-Enter`** on the highlighted problem and select either TSLint: fix current problem to fix only this particular issue or TSLint: fix current file to apply the fixes when possible to the whole file.

[image]

Comment: When I hovered on it I am not seeing those options. Is there anything that i need to install?

Comment: Run this at the root of your code:

tslint src/**/*.ts --fix

Comment: its working.Is there any other way other than writing in command line? I mean by clicking a button will get all the tslint errors fixed?

Answer (score 7):

You can create File Watcher in *Settings > Tools* by the following configuration:

[image]

On save (**Ctrl + s**), your current file will be fixed.

Comment: There is no option "Create file Watcher" in Intellij under Settings > Tools. Can you clarify where you find this?

Comment: JetBrains Documentation: In the Settings/Preferences dialog Ctrl+Alt+S, click File Watchers under Tools. The File Watchers page opens showing a list of File Watchers that are already configured in this project and in the IDE.

Click the Add button (+) and choose the predefined template from which you want to create a File Watcher. The choice depends on the tool you are going to use. To use a tool that is not on the list, choose Custom. The New Watcher dialog opens.

Comment: Program : $ProjectFileDir$\node_modules\.bin\tslint.cmd |||| Arguments : 
-c $ProjectFileDir$/tslint.json --fix $FilePath$

Comment: The file watcher settings is available only if the plugin is installed. Install it or see here for more info about file watcher: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-watchers.html#ws_filewatcher_type_and_location_of_input_files

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers probably only refer to Webstorm, as Filewatchers are not available in the current IntelliJ Ultimate edition (2020.2).

However, whenever you have your own `tslint.json`, for example when generating an Angular Project from cli, you can tell IntelliJ to use the specified code styles. To do this, open the tslint.json file (root of angular project) and you should see a prompting-bar at the top of your screen. Accept the prompt "Apply code style from TSLint?"

[image: bar appears at top of tslint.json file]

With the applied code style you can use your accustomed shortcuts (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+L) whenever you want to reformat a file / directory.

I found this solution (including the picture) on the Jetbrains forums https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000047844-Angular-and-Tslint-for-code-reformat

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run tslint against all files you would need to add it as an external tool.

A good write up from 2016 explains the process: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/08/using-external-tools/

Or you can always run it from the command line as Sajeetharan mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences => File Watchers => + ( create new )

Just remember to select the file type correct (its ok to create multiple watchers to handle other file types)
[image]

Comment: Where do you find File Watcher? That entry is nowhere to be found in my Intellij 2019.02 Ultimate.

Comment: @judos - see my answer above for newer IntelliJ versions. Just open the tslint.json and follow the prompt. (Sorry for the late reply - I didn't have enough karma yet)